# Self hosted WCF REST service Basic Authentication

Tags: rest, wcf, authentication, service

I have a self hosted WCF Rest Service, that works just fine, the one and only problem that I have is that when I access to de service URL, the browser prompts me for credentials, I validate with username and password and access the JSON results, but if I re enter the URL, the session remains logged in, and the browser does not prompts for credentials, the only way for this is to close the browser and re enter de URL.

Is ther any way, using basic authentication, for that the service ask for credentials every time I enter the URL?

Comment: Better add a lot more information (config files etc). Best would be a [mcve]